# Jquery hover -> slideDown on div with textfield: Autocomplete is treated as mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div container which makes another div container appear on mouseover/disappear on mouseout:

```
$('#my-escada').hover( 
    function() {  
        $(".login-popdown").stop(true,true).slideDown(500) ; 
    },
    function() { 
        $(".login-popdown").stop(true,true).slideUp(300) ;                     
    }
);
```

Within that appearing div container (class="login-popdown") is a textfield. The problem is as follows:

When I double click on that textfield the autocomplete suggestions are shown, which is fine, but when I mouseover on one of the options, Jquery treats it as mouseout and the slidedowned div disappears.

Is there a solution to this problem?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#my-escada').mousenter( 
    function() {  
        $(".login-popdown").stop(true,true).slideDown(500) ; 
    }
 );
 $('#my-escada').mouseleave(
    function() { 
        $(".login-popdown").stop(true,true).slideUp(300) ;
    }
);
```

Comment: could you provide a fiddle or url?

Comment: jsfiddle.com? does not work. never used it before, but it crashes when i try to run whatever code, even simple html without any js. Firebug: TypeError: this.editor.getCode is not a function. unfortunaely i cannot provide the real thing.

Comment: The problem you have is, that your mouse leaves the element as soon as you use the autofill, where is it added, inside or outside the #my-escada container?

Comment: i dont handle the autocomplete at all, it's done by the browser i guess and is activated for any html text field on default. pretty sure the element is added outside the container, because otherwise i dont see any reason why this wouldnt work.